# Is that possible to see *.exe reaching which files?

Tags: reverse-engineer

Sorry for my english i'm still trying to improve it. Let me explain my problem. I have a suspicious exe and i'm gonna run it on virtual machine. I want to see which folders or files it's try to reach (read and write). Is there any easy way for this ? Some kind reverse engineering tool maybe i don't know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something like this : http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/process_activity_view.html It's pretty easy to use. Just select your exe and it will list all files and folders exe trying to reach.